# 405 (Method Not Allowed) | AjaxUnAuthorized 405

Tags: c#, iis

I have below method:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("upload/ChunkedUpload")]
[ImpersonationFilterWebApi("ProjectFiles")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CommitChunks([FromUri] string dzIdentifier, [FromUri] string fileName, [FromUri] long expectedBytes, [FromUri] uint totalChunks, [FromUri] uint itemId) {
```

When I run it locally ( using VS ) **it works**.

When I deploy it to production server ( IIS 10 ) it throws below error:

javascript1?v=9zU3C3vkUYnLf2paLT6JsPUTvHXvlBbfxht3jJFWSEw1:9          PUT http://tms/api/files/upload/ChunkedUpload?dzIdentifier=85322f6a-7278-47af-8d31-adabb7ec3e48&fileName=9ea0d769&expectedBytes=9&totalChunks=1&itemId=1922539 405 (Method Not Allowed)

layout-global?v=7dFKsLh-DLUDvhoJPr74SU8y-KMSjoYyG3k5-fHCfkE1:1 AjaxUnAuthorized 405

[image]

Because locally (on my computer) it works but when I deploy this code to production it doesn't I suspect that production IIS somehow blocks PUT request.
I checked settings in IIS Manager, but didn't find anything suspecious ( or I don't know what to look for)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow steps and remove webdev module from the iis

1)Select Start, type Turn Windows features on or off in the Start Search box, and then select Turn Windows features on or off.

IF you are using server OS you can select "Remove Roles and Feature" from manage

[image]

2)In the Windows Features window, expand Internet Information Services ->  Common HTTP Features.

3)Uncheck the WebDAV Publishing feature. click Next and finish the uninstalling process.

4)Close iis server and open

If it still does not work you can add the PUT method in the iis:

1)Open iis server, Select your website

2)From the middle pane choose Request Filtering module

3)Select HTTP Verbs and Click Allow verbs from the action pane

[image]

4)Enter "PUT" in the add verb prompt , click ok

[image]

Note:

If you are dealing CORS request with the iis website it is recommended to install the iis CORS Module, here is the link to download the module:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed webdev and it started to work.